# adyen payment integration android 12+

Tags: java, android, kotlin

com.adyen.checkout.ui.internal.common.activity.RedirectHandlerActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'    ----> any one help me to resolve this issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

starting Android 12 you HAVE to set `android:exported` value for every `Activity`, `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` placed in manifest with accompanying `<intent-filter>` tag

[some info and example in changelog](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

problem exists in your imported library - developer of it should implement `exported` in its manifest. easiest way to resolve your problem is to update this library, I can see on Github it is maintained actively and probably supports Android 12 changes in newest version

Comment: i am already followed your step but still it was showing  these error msg while build a code "Installation failed due to: 'INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl706842158.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #339): com.adyen.checkout.ui.internal.common.activity.RedirectHandlerActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present'"

Comment: shall i add any activity or service tags regards this "com.adyen.checkout.ui.internal.common.activity.RedirectHandlerActivity" from manifest file

Comment: no, lib developer should add this `exported` line to its manifest. simply you are using old library which isn't supporting Android S, so your only way is to UPGRADE LIBRARY (which is in version 4 and you are still using 2)